# Why doesn't my useState array get emptied?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, onchange, use-state

My useState:

```
const [valuesToSearchFor, setValuesToSearchFor] = useState([]);
```

I have the following search input field with an onChange:

```
onChange={() => {
  setValuesToSearchFor(
  valuesToSearchFor.includes(value)
    ? valuesToSearchFor.filter(val => val !== value)
    : [...valuesToSearchFor, value]
  );
}}
```

This changes some data on my page like so:

```
{data.elements.filter((val) => {
  if(valuesToSearchFor.includes(val.name.toLowercase()){
      return val
  }
}
```

The only issue is when I delete the input field, it doesn't reflect in the array.
**Question** How can I empty out `valUesToSearchFor` so another search can be typed out in the input?

Comment: If you have one input, why is the state var called `valuesToSearchFor`, holding an array as opposed to `valueToSearchFor`, holding a string? If it really needs to be multiple values, I think you'd need a form element with a submit button to add values and a delete button for every added value.

Comment: Note that `onChange` get called with every key stroke. So if I type "apple", I get 5 events with the values "a", "ap", "app", "appl" and finally "apple" and seems like you're storing all that in the array which doesn't seem right.

Comment: `value` doesn't seem to be defined. Did you mean to get the input field value, eg `onChange={(e) => { const value = e.target.value; ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to say without seeing more of your code, but you should destructure your filtered `valuesToSearchFor`. Otherwise you're trying to modify a state prop directly

```js
onChange={(e) => {
  const value = e.target.value;
  setValuesToSearchFor(
    valuesToSearchFor.includes(value)
    ? [...valuesToSearchFor.filter((val) => val !== value)]
    : [...valuesToSearchFor, value]
  );
}}
```

As @Amiratak88 points out, this is going to push a new value to your array on every keystroke.

Again, not sure what you're trying to do, but you might opt to use buttons that update/reset your state.

```js
const MyComponent = () => {
  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState("");
  const [valuesToSearchFor, setValuesToSearchFor] = useState([]);

  return (
    <>
      <input
        onChange={(e) => {
          setSearchValue(e.target.value);
        }}
      />
      <button
        onClick={(e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          // update valuesToSearchFor with all unqiue values, including the current searchValue
          setValuesToSearchFor([...new Set([...valuesToSearchFor, searchValue])]);
        }}
      >
        Search
      </button>
      <button
        onClick={(e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          setValuesToSearchFor([]);
        }}
      >
        Reset
      </button>
    </>
  );
};
```